# JAX WS, JAXB and Null elements with attributes

Tags: attributes, jaxb, jax-ws, null

I am trying to consume a web service using JAXWS and wsimport. The WSIMPORT tool generated all the required classes and I can invoke the service without any issues.

However, I noticed in cases where response contains a nil element with valid attribute values, JAXWS fails to unmarshall it and throws a NullPointerException. I used SOAP UI to help debug and here's what I found. The response returns the following XML (Excerpt):

```
            <externalIdentifiers>
                 <identifierType code="2" name="Passport" xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                 <identifierValue/>
                 <issuingCountry xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
              </externalIdentifiers>
```

In my Java code, when trying to read the "name" property of identifier type as above, it throws a NPE:

```
      if(id.getIdentifierType() == null)
            {
                System.out.println("NULL");
            }
            System.out.println("Identifier Type: " + id.getIdentifierType().getName());
```

Output:

```
NULL
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

To me that does looks a reasonable response as in the response, identifierType is set as xsi:nil="true". That is also perfectly valid XML as per W3C. Question is, how do I read the attribute values such as code and name in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you can support this use case:

### Java Model

**ExternalIdentifiers**

You can change the `identifierType` property to be of type `JAXBElement<IdentifierType>` instead of `IdentifierType`.  To do this you will need to annotate the property with `@XmlElementRef`.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExternalIdentifiers {

    @XmlElementRef(name="identifierType")
    private JAXBElement<IdentifierType> identifierType;

    public JAXBElement<IdentifierType> getIdentifierType() {
        return identifierType;
    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

You will need a corresponding `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on a `creat`e method in a class annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="identifierType")
    public JAXBElement<IdentifierType> createIdentifierType(IdentifierType identifierType) {
        return new JAXBElement(new QName("identifierType"), IdentifierType.class, identifierType);
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**input.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<externalIdentifiers>
    <identifierType code="2" name="Passport" xsi:nil="true"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
</externalIdentifiers>
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ExternalIdentifiers.class, ObjectFactory.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum18834036/input.xml");
        ExternalIdentifiers externalIdentifiers = (ExternalIdentifiers) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(externalIdentifiers.getIdentifierType().getValue().getName());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Passport
```

### Note

Currently there is a bug in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) regarding this use case:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/404944

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the response and for pointing me in the right direction. How do I hook this into JAX-WS client? I tried creating an external binding file and using a class specification along with a ref attribute, but not sure how to hook the ObjectFactory.

I also realized the following in the binding file works as well:

>     <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
>       <xjc:simple/>
>     </jaxb:globalBindings>

However, it wraps everything inside a JAXBElement so I have to do a getValue on everything.
How do I hook what you suggested to work with JAX-WS client?